# How to force enter to active next input field in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

- Mobile web application contains order entry form.
- Rows contain product code and quantity.
- Mobile barcode scanner sends enter after barcode and this causes form to submit.

How to prevent form submit on enter: enter should behave like tab, it must:

- activate next input field.
- submit should done using submit button only.

jQuery, jQuery-mobile, ASP.NET MVC4 are used. Application is running in Motorola MC2180 computer using its WebKit based browser. This is modern browser and supports html5.

data entry page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <link href="/Scripts/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/applibrary.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
  <div>  
    <form id='inputform' method="post" 
       action ="/Detail/SaveFullDocument">
      <input type="hidden" name="_rows" />
      <table id="tableId">
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('tableId')" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Product" /></td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="Quantity" /></td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Product" /></td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="Quantity" /></td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
        </tr>
        ....
      </table>

        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('tableId')" />
        <input type="submit" value='Save' />
    </form>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).next('input').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

if all you need to focus next element upon enter, then no need to loop over all inputs as `$(this)` will be the target element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_nama/3yG5f/)**

Comment: maybe you can do `$(this).focus()`

Comment: to select next element using jQuery you can use the `next()` method, like `$(this).next('input').focus()`

Comment: try returning false at the end of your if condition `return false;` , you can also try binding multiple events `$('#inputform').on('keypress keydown keyup', 'input', function(){...});`

Comment: try this - `$('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input',
        function (event) {
          if (event.which == 13) {
            $(this).next('input').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });`

Comment: I tried but enter press is ignored. Console log contains `[input.ui-input-text ui-body-a, context: input.ui-input-text ui-body-a, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]`

Comment: I tested it in MC2180 Motorola mobile computer power saving was set to max perfonance and its default RoHS browser was used in Windiws CE6. Application was very slow, pressing key takes some seconds  for letter to appear. jquery , jquery-mobile or their style sheets cause this, this appears also without your code. I was forced to stop using browser and switched to use notepad insted.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it with jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(event){
    if(event.which()===13){ // 13 is the keyCode of enter Key
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, catch the enter, as the previous answer explained, then identify the next input field and call the .focus() method on it.

```
$(form).on('keyup', 'input', 
    function(event)
    {
        if(event.which() == 13)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); //this prevents the default, as was previouslynoted

            $.each($('input'), 
                function(index, input)
                {
                    if(input == this)
                    {
                       $('input')[index+1].focus();
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but got exception. I updated question and provided exception info. How to fix ?